# Yum stopped working after upgrading it

Tags: linux, fedora, yum

I just did `yum upgrade yum` and now I can't use it. It keeps showin this error:

```
[root@devlon5 www]# yum install pdftohtml
epel/primary_db           100% |=========================| 3.8 MB    00:00     
epel-erlang               100% |=========================| 2.3 kB    00:00     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in ?
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 254, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 109, in main
    result, resultmsgs = base.doCommands()
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 353, in doCommands
    self._getTs(needTsRemove)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/depsolve.py", line 99, in _getTs
    self._getTsInfo(remove_only)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/depsolve.py", line 110, in _getTsInfo
    pkgSack = self.pkgSack
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 774, in <lambda>
    pkgSack = property(fget=lambda self: self._getSacks(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 564, in _getSacks
    self.repos.populateSack(which=repos)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/repos.py", line 279, in populateSack
    sack.populate(repo, mdtype, callback, cacheonly)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 164, in populate
    if self._check_db_version(repo, mydbtype):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 223, in _check_db_version
    return repo._check_db_version(mdtype)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 1227, in _check_db_version
    repoXML = self.repoXML
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 1417, in <lambda>
    repoXML = property(fget=lambda self: self._getRepoXML(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 1409, in _getRepoXML
    self._loadRepoXML(text=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 1399, in _loadRepoXML
    return self._groupLoadRepoXML(text, self._mdpolicy2mdtypes())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 1375, in _groupLoadRepoXML
    self._commonRetrieveDataMD(mdtypes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 1348, in _commonRetrieveDataMD
    urlgrabber.progress.text_meter_total_size(0)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'text_meter_total_size'
```

Is it because its dependencies are outdated?

Can anybody help me to resolve this.
Thank you so much

Comment: Where did you get your updated yum from? And, uh, are you really using EPEL with Fedora?

Comment: i just did yum upgrade yum -- and I'm not sure about the EPEL as this is something that has been setup for me few years back. is it possible to rollback the upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

The above error is from using a very out of date python-urlgrabber (roughly RHEL-5 GA), with a newer version of yum than is in RHEL-5. The rawhide rebuild one?

It is technically still a bug though, you can copy the code from __init__.py:

```
                if hasattr(urlgrabber.progress, 'text_meter_total_size'):
                    urlgrabber.progress.text_meter_total_size(remote_size,
                                                              local_size)
```

Answer (score 1):

yum uses python. So you should upgrade python before upgrading yum.

Instead of rolling back yum I would upgrade python manually using `rpm -Uvh`.